# is there a way add a single value to an existing query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

So we are now setup to run all SQL queries off a Restful API, this one I figured out already how to retrieve a full list of students like this,

```
|ID|  FirstNm  |  LastNm | address | phone | cell |      
|---|------------|-----------|-----------|--------|---------|     
|---|------------|-----------|-----------|-----|------------|
```

but what if I want to display on top of the list, the Teacher's name, the school name etc. The data is coming from different tables. Is it possible to include into the existing query (with some function to grab only one record). Or would it be necessary to run another API call?

What I have so far the processing in the API:

```
if ($operation == 'studentlist') {
    $schoolid = $_GET['schoolid'];
    $result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_student where SchoolID='" . $schoolid . "'", $cnx);
    $recipes = array();
    while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $recipes[] = $recipe;
    }
    $output = json_encode(array('data' => $recipes));
    echo $output;
}
```

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    _____________________________________________________________
    |                                                            |
    |   ______ "Ms. Jefferson's" Class -- Student List___        |   
    |____________________________________________________________|  
    |                                                            |                                                       
    | ID|  FirstNm   |  LastNm   |  address  | Phone  | cell fon |                                                   
    |---|------------|-----------|-----------|--------|----------|     
    |---|------------|-----------|-----------|--------|----------|
```

That should give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve... "Ms. Jeffeson" would be the teachers name...

Comment: Show us some data sample and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to join tables in your query. We don't know what the table structure is, but it would likely be something like "select * from tbl_student s join tbl_student_to_teacher_map map on s.id=map.student_id join tbl_teacher t on t_id=map.teacher_id"

Comment: there is another table that contains the school data pertaining to this class.  so I can add to the above query the 'teacherName' and 'schoolName' FROM school_table WHERE id = $schoolid....  but I don't need the new data for each row. only on the top of the table....

Comment: again that doesnt help, show us data and desire output

Comment: I will post a sample as a answer to the question...

Comment: Put that in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Done just that. Thanx all